# how to add space in ZPL

Tags: zpl-ii

I'm using printer Zebra ZM400.

I want to print text box and insert a text follow by marking line.
I want fix below code as my text box coordination

How to set the marking line with right alignment and center alignment in the text box?
Note: from the code, left alignment is generated

```
^FO500,245^GB240,165,5^FS
^FO545,255^A0N,30,20^FD{MARK LINE 1}^FS
^FO545,285^A0N,30,20^FD{MARK LINE 2}^FS
^FO545,315^A0N,30,20^FD{MARK LINE 3}^FS
^FO545,345^A0N,30,20^FD{MARK LINE 4}^FS
^FO545,375^A0N,30,20^FD{MARK LINE 5}^FS
^FO545,405^A0N,30,20^FD{MARK LINE 6}^FS
^FO545,335^A0N,30,20^FD{MARK LINE 7}^FS
```

Other question:
How to add space at the beginning of text in ZPL?

Answer (score 3):

You can define with the "^FB" command a "Field Block" in which you can print text centered:

```
^FO0,0^FB464,10,0,C,0^ADN,20, 10^FDImCentered^FS
```

Code above is not tested by me, but it should created on position 0,0 a field block with a length of 464 Pixel and for max 10 lines in which "ImCentered" is dumped out in the middle of the line.

Comment: The length is not in pixels. It is in dots. Pixels have no meaning for printers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to design, but if you want to design complicated labels, you can always use [Zebra Designer](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/index/products/software/label_design_software/zebradesignerpro.html) to design your labels in a GUI and get the ZPL code out of it.